# Python codes about class or multi-line animation?

Tags: python, class, animation

I am a novice of python. The problem that I am trying is about optimization. I wanna compare two optimization algorithms, namely RMSprop and Adam with Beale function. Actually, I download the Adam algorithm online and add PMSprop to the original code. But the animation figure shows me that the particle paths of two algorithms are surprisingly same. (The path flashes.) I am sure that they should be different. And I try some severe changes of class RMSprop but the result does not change. I am not sure which step is wrong. Animation step? Or the step of calling class?

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import autograd.numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib import animation

from autograd import elementwise_grad,value_and_grad,grad
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import zip_longest
from functools import partial 

f = lambda x,y: (1.5 - x + x*y)**2 + (2.25 - x + x*y**2)**2 + (2.625 - x 
+x*y**3)**2

xmin, xmax, xstep = -4.5, 4.5, 0.2
ymin, ymax, ystep = -4.5, 4.5, 0.2

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xmin, xmax + xstep, xstep),np.arange(ymin, ymax 
+ ystep, ystep))
z = f(x,y)

minima = np.array([3.0,0.5])
minima_ = minima.reshape(-1,1)

def target_func(weights):
  x,y = weights
  return f(x,y)

class Adam:
  def __init__(self, loss, weights, lr=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8):
        self.loss = loss
        self.theta = weights
        self.lr = lr          #　learning rate
        self.beta1 = beta1
        self.beta2 = beta2
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.get_gradient = grad(loss)
        self.m = 0
        self.v = 0
        self.t = 0
  def minimize_trace(self, path=[]):
        self.t +=1
        g = self.get_gradient(self.theta)
        self.m =  self.beta1 * self.m + (1 - self.beta1) * g
        self.v = self.beta2 * self.v + (1 - self.beta2) * (g * g)
        self.m_hat = self.m / (1 - self.beta1 ** self.t)
        self.v_hat = self.v / (1 - self.beta2 ** self.t)
        self.theta -= self.lr * self.m_hat / (self.v_hat ** 0.5 + self.epsilon)
        path.append(np.copy(self.theta))

class RMSprop:
    def __init__(self, loss, weights, lr=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, 
    epsilon=1e-8):
        self.loss = loss
        self.theta = weights
        self.lr = lr          #　learning rate
        self.beta1 = beta1
        self.beta2 = beta2
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.get_gradient = grad(loss)
        self.m = 0
        self.v = 0
        self.t = 0
    def minimize_trace(self, path=[]):
        self.t +=1
        g = self.get_gradient(self.theta)
  ##            self.m =  self.beta1 * self.m + (1 - self.beta1) * g
        self.v = self.beta2 * self.v + (1 - self.beta2) * (g * g)
        self.m_hat = self.m / (1 - self.beta1 ** self.t)
        self.v_hat = self.v / (1 - self.beta2 ** self.t)
        self.theta -= self.lr * self.m_hat / (self.v_hat ** 0.5 + 
        self.epsilon)
        path.append(np.copy(self.theta))
EPOCHS = 3000
SHOW_STEPS = 100
PRECISION = 1e-8
weights = np.array([1,1.5])
path_trace_adam = [np.copy(weights)]
path_trace_rmsprop = [np.copy(weights)]

adam = Adam(target_func, weights, lr = 0.01)
rmsprop = RMSprop(target_func, weights, lr = 0.01)

for i in range(EPOCHS):
  adam.minimize_trace(path_trace_adam)
  rmsprop.minimize_trace(path_trace_rmsprop) 
print("\n final weights:{} loss:{}".format(adam.theta, adam.loss(adam.theta)))
print("\n final weights:{} loss:{}".format(rmsprop.theta, rmsprop.loss(rmsprop.theta)))


path_trace_adam = np.array(path_trace_adam).T
path_trace_rmsprop = np.array(path_trace_rmsprop).T


shape_adam = path_trace_adam.shape
shape_rmsprop = path_trace_rmsprop.shape

if shape_adam[1] > SHOW_STEPS:  
  show_step_adam = shape_adam[1] // SHOW_STEPS
  path_trace_adam = np.array(path_trace_adam[:,::show_step_adam])
if shape_rmsprop[1] > SHOW_STEPS:  
  show_step_rmsprop = shape_rmsprop[1] // SHOW_STEPS
  path_trace_rmsprop = np.array(path_trace_rmsprop[:,::show_step_rmsprop])

##################   Visualize Convergence Trace
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

ax.contour(x, y, z, levels=np.logspace(0, 5, 35), norm=LogNorm(), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
ax.plot(*minima_, 'r*', markersize=12)

line_adam, = ax.plot([], [], 'r', label='Adam Optimizer', lw=2)
line_rmsprop, = ax.plot([], [], 'k', label='RMSprop Optimizer', lw=2)
point_adam, = ax.plot([], [], 'ro')
point_rmsprop, = ax.plot([], [], 'ko')

ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')

ax.set_xlim((xmin, xmax))
ax.set_ylim((ymin, ymax))

ax.legend(loc='upper left')
###################  animation
def init_adam():
    line_adam.set_data([], [])
    point_adam.set_data([], [])
    return line_adam, point_adam

def init_rmsprop():
    line_rmsprop.set_data([], [])
    point_rmsprop.set_data([], [])
    return line_rmsprop, point_rmsprop

def animate_adam(i):
    line_adam.set_data(*path_trace_adam[::,:i])
    point_adam.set_data(*path_trace_adam[::,i-1:i])
    return line_adam, point_adam

def animate_rmsprop(i):
    line_rmsprop.set_data(*path_trace_rmsprop[::,:i])
    point_rmsprop.set_data(*path_trace_rmsprop[::,i-1:i])
    return line_rmsprop, point_rmsprop

anim_adam = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_adam, init_func=init_adam,
                           frames=path_trace_adam.shape[1], interval=60, 
                           repeat_delay=None, repeat=True, blit=True)

anim_rmsprop = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_rmsprop, init_func=init_rmsprop,
                           frames=path_trace_rmsprop.shape[1], interval=60, 
                           repeat_delay=None, repeat=True, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To make it easier for others to answer your question, can you give more context on the animation library that you use? It will be great if you can post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve] of your problem

Comment: @AdityaSantoso I've updated the complete codes. But apologize that they are so messy....

Comment: What if you separate the RMSprop routine to one module and Adam with Beale one to separate module and run only one at a time? it's a bit hard to tell from the code whether the two are independent (I believe so?)

Comment: I try some tests. It seems that every time adam.minimize_trace(path_trace_adam) runs, the variable "weights" will change. I can not tell why it happens. The variable "weights" is defined before as "weights = np.array([1,1.5])". I think it should be fixed...

Answer (score 0):

The bug is here:

```py
weights = np.array([1,1.5])
# ... truncated for brevity
adam = Adam(target_func, weights, lr = 0.01) 
rmsprop = RMSprop(target_func, weights, lr = 0.01)
```

Since the reference to `weights` is shared between the two routines, every time `Adam.minimize_trace` and `RMSprop.minimize_trace` run, they modify the same array. Since the path is derived from the array, the path on both become the same.

If you copy the array before passing it to the two constructors, it should work as expected.

```py
adam = Adam(target_func, np.copy(weights), lr = 0.01)
rmsprop = RMSprop(target_func, np.copy(weights), lr = 0.01)
```